# Unable to AddFieldByFieldName elements for custom index

Tags: content-search, solr, indexing

Using Sitecore 9.1 I'm trying to add some custom index fields and my config patch is throwing the below error when I add `AddFieldByField` name elements:

> [ConfigurationException: Unable to process 'AddFieldByFieldName'
>   config section.]
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap.AddFieldByFieldName(XmlNode
>   configNode) +909
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +142    Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +859
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean
>   deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +620
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +320
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode
>   paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +109
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean
>   deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +527
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +320
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +170
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +116
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode
>   paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +109
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean
>   deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +527
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +320
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode
>   paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +941
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean
>   deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +527
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +320
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()
>   +311    Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.Initialize()
>   +21    (Object , Object ) +9    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>   +236    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +215
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +1184
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +581
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +277
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +369
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +111    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +714

If I comment out those 3 elements then site loads fine.  My patch is:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultEventsIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>
            <include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">
              <EventDetails>{5C873C37-68F7-4B90-BE99-C60083AE459F}</EventDetails>

            </include>
            <include hint="list:AddIncludedField">

              <contentheading>{119570A4-0810-4D81-88CD-E64E4D4DD0D6}</contentheading>
              <contentintro>{239319A2-488E-4CA9-B0C9-99876FA8B74F}</contentintro>
              <startdate>{83D79FDC-7D0C-412F-9F9F-F007C17A52C0}</startdate>

            </include>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <!--<field fieldName="urllink">TAC.Utils.Search.UrlComputedField, TAC.Utils</field>-->
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
          <initializeOnAdd>false</initializeOnAdd>
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
              <typeMatch typeName="text" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_t" cultureFormat="_{1}" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="datetime" type="System.DateTime" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdt" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              <typeMatch typeName="string" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
            </typeMatches>
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="contentheading" returntype="text"/>
              <field fieldName="contentintro" returntype="text"/>
              <field fieldName="startdate" returntype="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"/>

            </fieldNames>

          </fieldMap>
          <!-- **** Inherited default configuration **** -->
          <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders" />
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/indexFieldStorageValueFormatter" />
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/indexDocumentPropertyMapper" />
          <documentBuilderType ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentBuilderType" />

        </defaultEventsIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Not sure what I'm missing as the fieldMap section contains the types of my fields (as suggested by other posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore configs are case sensitive.

Your config contains `returntype` with lowercase `t` character.

It should be `returnType` with capitacl case `T`.

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="contentheading" returnType="text"/>
  <field fieldName="contentintro" returnType="text"/>
  <field fieldName="startdate" returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"/>
</fieldNames>
```

Comment: Nice one - thanks :)

Comment: @marek is there any documentation you know of that defines what you can put in `<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">` section? I'm at a total loss. For example, here there is a `format="xxx"` but what other attributes or sub-elements are supported for SOLR config? How do you know `format="xx"` is a supported attribute and not just ignored?

Comment: Just check what Sitecore uses in its own configs

Comment: When I was messing with this. I noticed that the fieldName is not a recognized field. It throws an error "The given key was not present in the dictionary". I dotpeeked at the implementation, and the keys AddFieldByFieldName is looking for are "fieldTypeName","returnType", and "boost" The fieldTypeName and returnType are required or you'll get an "Unable to process 'AddFieldByFieldName' config section." error. Maybe changed since this post.